# Empty Scope vs Anonymous Action Delegate

Tags: c#

I don't want to ask which way is better, so I'll ask if there are any performance implications for using an anonymous action delegate vs using an empty scope to encase a variable declaration? Also, are there situations where one would be beneficial over the other?

Option 1:

```
for (i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
    // do stuff
}

// empty scope so I don't use a variable declared in enclosing scope above
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (object thisObject in MyObjects)
    {
        // do stuff
        i++
        if (i >= something)
        {
            break;
            // not doing anything else so this will exit the empty scope
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
for (i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
    // do stuff
}

// Anonymous action delegate so I don't use a variable declared in enclosing scope above    
new Action(() =>
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (object thisObject in MyObjects)
    {
        // do stuff
        i++
        if (i >= something)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
})();
```

Also, if you believe there is a smell here, let me know.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; ...` would avoid all this. Limit the scope to what you need, or introduce a new method/local function to separate old and new. Explicitly opening a scope is almost never needed, explicitly declaring a lambda to immediately invoke even less -- this isn't JavaScript.

Comment: Re-using a variable like that creates confusion in my opinion.

Comment: "Empty scope" has no effect on code generation quality, a delegate however can't be optimized away.  Surely most everybody would use a better text editor.

Comment: Why not use a different variable name?

Comment: OK, I doubled back on my other variable and realized I could use a more descriptive name to make it less confusing. i.e. for (int current = 0; current < limit; current++) I was too focused on the new variable instead of the old. Thanks!

Comment: That's good. It would be really confusing to come across this and see something in an `Action`, wonder why, and then find out that it was to re-use `i` as a variable name.